# How to add gem dependencies that host on other site in a gemspec file?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

In a gemspec file, is there a way to add dependency gem that hosts on other sites like github? I build a gem that has a dependency to http://github.com/mbleigh/mash. I checked the method add_dependency, but it seems it doesn't have that functionality. Could anyone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, AFAIK you can't.
It's responsibility of the end-user to add additional sources to its gem configuration in order to download third-party Gems.

Some applications, such as Bundler and Rails, also allows the developer to define which is the Gem source for a specific Gem.
I agree it would be a nice option in the `.gemspec` file itself.